# Is this equation a parabola or a hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, finance

In a [1972 paper](http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~nchristo/statistics_c183_c283/analytic_derivation_frontier.pdf) by Robert Merton, the following equation is derived:

$$\sigma(\mu;A,B,C,D)=\sqrt{\frac{A \mu^2-2B\mu+C}{D}}$$

This is known as the Markowitz frontier in finance.  When this is plotted, the convention is to measure $\mu$ along the y-axis and $\sigma$ along the x-axis. Regardless of which variable is assigned to which axis, the result is a parabola (or maybe a hyperbola?)-looking thing.

In his paper Merton calls it a parabola.  However, I recently saw an online lecture given at Yale university wherein Robert Shiller calls it a hyperbola.

Both Merton and Shiller are Nobel laureates.  Which one is correct?

EDIT: Ah!  To be fair to Merton, in his paper he doesn't call the above equation a parabola.  He does, however, call the *square* of the above equation a parabola (pp. 1854).  Does the above equation become a parabola if you square it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $B^2 < AC$ and $AD>0$ such that the expression under the square root sign is always positive, this produces (one branch of) a *hyperbola*.

To see it's not a parabola, simply note that for large $\mu$ the graph asymptotically approaches $\sigma=\left|\mu-\frac BA\right|\sqrt{A/D}$, which is not how a parabola behaves.

On the other hand, it's clearly a second-degree curve (square both sides to get a quadratic equation in $\sigma$ and $\mu$), and the only conic section that has asymptotes is a hyperbola.

The expression under the square root sign (and thus $\sigma^2$ as a function of $\mu$) does indeed produce a parabola.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Thanks!  I just realized I may have slandered poor Merton.  See edit.

Comment: @ben: Yes, the fraction produces a parabola.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Apologies to Merton and Shiller.  Both were correct.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the radicand is positive for all $\mu$ (i.e., that $A/D > 0$ and $B^{2} - AC < 0$), it's (one branch of) a hyperbola, with asymptotes $\sigma = \pm \sqrt{A/D} \mu$.

Answer (score 1):

A hyperbola can be defined such that for the general quadratic equation

$$ax^2+2bxy+cy^2+dx+ey+f=0$$

we have that $ac-b^2<0$.  Here, we have

$$A\mu^2-D\sigma^2-2B\mu+C=0$$

Then, if $-AD<0$, then the quadratic is a hyperbola and Shiller was correct.

---

**NOTE:**

If the dependent variable is considered to be the variance $\sigma^2$, then quadratic is a parabola and Merton was correct.

The conclusion is that the answer depends on whether one considers the dependent variable to be the standard deviation $\sigma$, in which case the expression is hyperbolic, or one considers the dependent variable to be the variance $\sigma^2$, in which case the expression is parabolic.